# Shell problems when running scripts in Ubuntu as new user

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, dos

When I log into a particular Ubuntu Linux (10.04 64bit) host via SSH, I get a bash shell. From here I am able to run a particular Python script, with the executable bit set, that has this as the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

However if another (new) user logs into the same host via SSH and tries to run this (or a copy of this) script, they get this error:

```
$ ./script.py
: No such file or directory
```

It turns out that this file is actually a DOS line-ending file, yet I can run this fine from my login. If I convert it to UNIX format, then the other person can also run it fine.

The script also runs fine for both of us if we prefix it with 'python', regardless of DOS/UNIX format:

```
$ python ./script.py
blah blah blah...
```

Further to this, once the script is converted to UNIX format and the other user can run it, it's still not runnable from a Makefile - make displays the same error as above.

I read that /bin/sh is the 'dash' (not 'bash') shell in Ubuntu and I'm wondering if that has something to do with this, as it behaves differently to bash. If so, I'd like to know what the difference is between my login (which works perfectly fine and has done for years) and this new user's login which is displaying all sorts of weird behaviour. Where to start looking?

Also perhaps relevant - the new user was created automatically by the Likewise service (an Active Directory integration client) and it's possible that this service has configured the new user incorrectly in some way.

I've also tried changing the first line to #!/usr/bin/python with no difference.

Both users are running the **bash** shell as their login shell.

Comment: Do you have `/usr/bin/env` installed?  Does `/usr/bin/env python` run from the command line?  Also, the shell's name is "bash".

Comment: @S.Lott: *One* of the shells is named "bash". The OP is referring to the default provider of `sh` on Ubuntu systems which is the Debian Almquist SHell (`dash`).

Comment: Tried a third user, also new (so Likewise creates a new account with a different name) and this one has no issues. The problem seems to be isolated to the first new user.

Comment: @S.Lott: Yes, /usr/bin/env is installed and /usr/bin/env python does run from the command line. BTW there are two shells in common use in Ubuntu - bash is typically the login shell, and dash is typically the 'sh' shell.

Comment: @meowsqueak: Please do not comment.  Please **update** your question to contain **all** the facts.

Comment: What's wrong with responding by comment? These comments directly follow on from the question and are part of the original question.

Comment: @meowsqueak: Please, don't think of yourself.  Please think of the millions of other users who search by title and scan the question.  They will not read the comments.  Please make the question **complete** and **current** so that people other than you can understand it.  All of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this and I shall answer it myself for completeness.

The problem stems from the fact that we are using git, on Cygwin/Windows, with core.autocrlf=true. We do this for various reasons and it's non-trivial to change.

The original new user who logged into the Linux machine also copied their Cygwin .gitconfig, which contained core.autocrlf=true, to their new account. Then they cloned the git repository that contained the python script in question. I didn't include this information in the original question because I simply hadn't made the connection. I didn't want to confuse the issue by explaining things that seemed irrelevant. Hindsight eh?

Anyway, this made all the scripts in the clone DOS-format and this explains why nothing would work properly for this user. It also explains why the error messages weren't useful, because the ^M carriage return character was returning the cursor to the start of the line without a linefeed and then the "No such file or directory" was overwriting the useful part of the message. I spotted this when I set the PATH to a directory with no permission, and got the corrupted message "Permission deniedn" - that rogue 'n' got me thinking.

So my initial assumption that we were all running the same script (since they all came from the same git repository) was wrong - we weren't actually running the same script at all. For most of us it was a UNIX-format python script, but for this one user it was DOS-format instead. Turns out to be quite a simple problem in the end, but once again we're bitten by a Windows-related issue. Won't be the last time.

Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and it was not immediately clear from the above answers what the problem was, or what the solution was, however I think I now understand.

Apparently windows line breaks are encoded slightly differently. While cygwin can encode in a unix format, I was using a windows text editor (Notepad++) to write my scripts and the default format is windows CRLF encoding. Notepad++ can be reconfigured for unix as the default format. All of the scripts generated by my coworkers on linux or mac machines would work fine, but then I would edit them in windows, and it did not occur to me that there could be a problem until I tried running one on a linux machine.

Firstly, this can be diagnosed in either cygwin or bash with:

```
cat -v file.py
```

where each line will have a ^M at the end if it is in DOS format

Secondly, cygwin has a simple converter:

```
d2u file.py
```

and you can check to see if that worked as in the first step.
All of my scripts would then run as usual.

Answer (score 3):

The mystery is why you're able to run it without conversion. All the other behavior is expected since your shebang is telling `env` to execute `python^M` which doesn't exist. *Or does it?* If you have a symlink or script named `python^M` in your `$PATH` (but not in the other user's) that would explain this odd behavior. Do `type -a python^M` (press Ctrl-V then Ctrl-M to produce the `^M`).

If you change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python` there *should* be a difference. You should get `-bash: ./script.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` instead of `: No such file or directory`.

Comment: You've provided the clue that I needed to crack this - my main concern was why didn't I get the same behaviour for other users. It turns out that the problem is with git configuration - the script came out of a git repository. The new user copied their .gitconfig from their Cygwin installation, which happened to contain core.autocrlf=true - this converted all scripts in the repository to DOS format. That's why there was a difference between users.